# Icon exists in systray?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, system-tray, systray

I want to check if an icon exists in the systray; as in, if "X" application has displayed their systray icon in the systray area.

I've Googled for information about how to do this but I didn't find anything.

> UPDATE :

This what I've tried in VB.NET translating the C# examples of the url gived by Robert comment, but I don't know how to continue it.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hWndChildAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr

    Public Shared Function WindowHandle(sTitle As String) As Long
        Return FindWindow(vbNullString, sTitle)
    End Function


    Private Shared Function GetSystemTrayHandle() As IntPtr
        Dim hWndTray As IntPtr = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", Nothing)
        If hWndTray <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "TrayNotifyWnd", Nothing)
            If hWndTray <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "SysPager", Nothing)
                If hWndTray <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                    hWndTray = FindWindowEx(hWndTray, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", Nothing)
                    Return hWndTray
                End If
            End If
        End If

        Return IntPtr.Zero
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(WindowHandle("Steam")) ' 6687230
        MsgBox(GetSystemTrayHandle()) ' 62789
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: you want to do it for your application or 3rd party app?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/4c4f60ce-3573-433d-994e-9c17f95187f0/

Comment: Thanks for comment, is for a 3rd party app

Comment: @Robert thanks but I can't understand it at all

Comment: I'd have to reproduce it in my lab to explain it to you.  Extract of bat wing will probably be involved.

Comment: You should read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10497/A-tool-to-order-the-window-buttons-in-your-taskbar) code-project article.